# Is USB 3 dual role a hardware or software configuration or both?

Tags: usb, peripherals

So, on USB 2 OTG, in order for OTG support to be enabled, the USB port and the USB controller had to be built for it. This hardware distinction is made very deliberately on devices that carry it. For example, Raspberry Pi devices are marketed with USB OTG devices as being a separate feature from the other USB ports.

On Rock Pi's this feature is either hard coded or has a physical toggle to switch from standard USB to USB OTG.

It is very easy to find devices that support USB 2 OTG, but I find it harder to find devices that support USB 3 OTG/Dual-Role. I'm beginning to wonder if Dual Role comes with (and is assumed to be on) all USB 3 ports or that no one other than Smart Phone manufacturers make them.

I [seem to be struggling to find this kind of hardware,](https://superuser.com/questions/1754976/usb-3-drp-otg-on-sbcs) and I am unsure as to why I can't find any

Articles like [this one on Microsoft,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/usb-dual-role-driver-stack-architecture) give me the impression that it is a software configuration.

So is USB 3 Dual-Role a software configuration or hardware configuration or both?

Comment: I have only seen it on phones and some tablets. Usb C tends to be more common these days in dual role, on many devices.

Comment: Potential duplicate:https://superuser.com/questions/1681119/pc-to-pc-file-transfer-with-usb-c-%E2%86%94-usb-c-or-usb-c-%E2%86%94-usb-ordinary-cables-is-it At least the answers are reasonably on-topic in that they state "if the computer/device supports acting as client/host or can negotiate" and it falls down to what either side supports.

Comment: @Mokubai This question is intended to be a bit more inclusive on all OTG/Dual-role features. For example Linux Gadgets, RNDIS, badusb automation, KVM over OTG (like PiKVM), etc. Not just MTP file shares, but I will take a look at it.

Comment: I didn't say anything about MTP and neither really does the question. The question states "PC to PC file transfer" which could be any method such as IP-over-USB, one of the answers mentions "IP over Thunderbolt" which would infer SAMBA or some other method. As I say, it kind of falls down to what either side of the connection supports. MTP is how USB2 handled it, but that is only a useful method for smart devices which are working over a somewhat limited protocol, i.e. USB 2.

Comment: @Mokubai I've reviewed the material in that thread, and while a lot of those answers could be used to answer this one, that question is heavily focused on simply File Sharing over USB-C, not necessarily how to setup Dual Role. In fact a lot of the information in there references Host-to-Host cables, which have nothing to do with Dual-Role.