# Connect Mac to PC with USB-C cable

Tags: macos, usb

If I connect my Macbook (2021 M1 Pro with Ventura 13.3.1) to PC with a USB-C cable, I see a "NCM Data" device on device manager (which doesn't get installed because no driver is found - Hardware ID is USB\VID_05AC&PID_1902&REV_1803&MI_01 and MI_03) and also a unnamed device on Network Adapters section (USB\VID_05AC&PID_1902&REV_1803&MI_00 and MI_02).

Is there anyway I can enabled those devices to transfer files between the two computers using the USB cable?

Comment: USB is not a networking protocol on the Mac. If you enable File Sharing on both computers, you might be able to make the transfer via Wi-Fi. But the best way is to go through a router.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PC to PC file transfer with USB-C ↔ USB-C or USB-C ↔ USB ordinary cables. Is it possible?](https://superuser.com/questions/1681119/pc-to-pc-file-transfer-with-usb-c-%e2%86%94-usb-c-or-usb-c-%e2%86%94-usb-ordinary-cables-is-it)